# ERROR: build kernel Failed

Tags: compiling, arm

I recently got a nanopi m1 and I am using [the official documentation](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_M1#Make_Your_Own_Debian)

I downloaded the lichee source code and this toolchain: `gcc-linaro-arm.tar.xz` as the documentation said, but when I try to compile the source code, I got this error:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
ERROR: build kernel Failed
```

Is it a compiler problem?

I am running Ubuntu 17.04 and I am a beginner in both arm processor and Linux environment but I have a background in electronics

whole code:

```
    ./build.sh -p sun8iw7p1 -b nanopi-h3
INFO: ----------------------------------------
INFO: build lichee ...
INFO: chip: sun8iw7p1
INFO: platform: linux
INFO: business: 
INFO: kernel: linux-3.4
INFO: board: nanopi-h3
INFO: output: out/sun8iw7p1/linux/nanopi-h3
INFO: ----------------------------------------
INFO: build kernel ...
INFO: prepare toolchain ...
INFO: skip kernel clean for nanopi-h3 Linux system.
Building kernel
/home/sami/lichee/linux-3.4/output/lib/modules/3.4.39-h3
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: 'include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
/home/sami/lichee/linux-3.4/./Kbuild:35: recipe for target 'kernel/bounds.s' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 1
Makefile:986: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
scripts/Makefile.build:307: recipe for target 'scripts/mod/empty.o' failed
make[2]: *** [scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:443: recipe for target 'scripts/mod' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts/mod] Error 2
Makefile:507: recipe for target 'scripts' failed
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
ERROR: build kernel Failed
INFO: use a fake rootfs.ext4.
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.00234644 s, 447 MB/s
mke2fs 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)

Filesystem too small for a journal
INFO: ----------------------------------------

INFO: build sun8iw7p1 linux  lichee OK

INFO: ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: you can retrieve all commands by up arrow when inside the terminal and then you may highlight the whole commmand with the mouse (left-to-right or right-to-left doesn't matter) and then `ctrl-shift-C` to copy from terminal. Pasting here will be normal `ctrl-V` it's just you need to add `shift` in terminal for copy and paste because both are already mapped to something else.

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: guys i am waiting for your help

Comment: i don't know. all in all this is definitely not the place for this issue ubuntu isn't at fault here. if you can pull it off under windows but not under ubuntu with the same set of commands maybe. but it doesn't look like this is the case. this issue goes here : https://github.com/friendlyarm/h3_lichee/issues make a new issue. i found the line from your output here  :  https://github.com/friendlyarm/h3_lichee/blob/master/buildroot/scripts/mkcmd.sh but I don't know what ` -e rootfs.ext4 ` being `false` for you means or if that's even a bad thing seems like the script either couldn't find the ...

Comment: ...drive or couldn't succesfully partition it to rootfs. so make sure the SD is accessible and pointed to correctly. but in the end noone here can solve your issue. https://www.google.fr/search?q=INFO%3A+use+a+fake+rootfs.ext4.&oq=INFO%3A+use+a+fake+rootfs.ext4.&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.830j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: ok tatsu i know where to go

Comment: no worries man ;-)